# Complex baseband impulse response

Tags: discrete-signals

The IEEE 802.15.4 matlab code for wireless body area networks gives a matrix **h** representing the complex impulse response of the channel. The size of each realization of h is 1*38. I want to transmit a signal ***x*** of size 1*2048 samples over this channel. What operation should be done between **h** and ***x***? multiplication or convolution?

Comment: Convolution, which can be achieved via matlab conv

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the output of an LTI system (like a communications channel as modeled here), given an input signal $x[n]$ and the system's impulse response $h[n]$, you use convolution:

$$
y[n] = x[n] * h[n]
$$

$y[n]$ is the channel output.

Comment: How can I convolve a complex X vector with a complex  h vector in matlab? @Jason R

Comment: Using the `conv()` function.

Comment: When I convolve *x* 1*2048 with *h* 1*38 the ouput is if length 1*2085 why?
@Jason R

Comment: What will the mathematical operation done in the receiver to cancel the effect of h?
@Jason R

Comment: Those are different questions. If you don't understand how convolution works, you won't get far. I suggest studying more introductory signal theory.

Comment: I know how convolution work but i need the signal after channel still has the same length of 2048 ?
@ Jason R